# How to make an email with submit button, which triggers a post request

Tags: html, email, security, outlook

I want to send an email which has a submit button, on click of which, a post request would be triggered.
How can I create such an email?
What kind of code would be required?

The code I have written:

```
<h1>Show a push button:</h1>

<p>The button below activates a JavaScript when it is clicked.</p>
<br/>

<input type="button" value="Click me" onclick="msg()">
```

Answer (score 0):

That approach you appear to be trying to take is to use JavaScript. This absolutely will not work. **Email clients do not allow JavaScript to execute** in HTML formatted email.

---

You could place a regular form inside the email:

```
<form action="http://example.com" method="POST">
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

… however, **form support in email clients is not perfect**.

---

The **safe** approach is to ask the user to do a two-step process: use **a regular link** to a webpage containing the form which the user can load in their web browser and then click the submit button for.

If you don't care about the usual protections, then you could have JavaScript submit the form on that page automatically, or change the endpoint that expects a POST request to expect a GET request and use a regular link in the original email.